# SMARTY forach and adding new clearfix element braking lines

Tags: html, loops, foreach, smarty, clearfix

I have code:

```
{foreach from=$liconteiners item=lconteiner name=sld}
        <li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
{/foreach}
```

and this is give me something like this:

```
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
```

but I need to add after every four li another li: `<li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>`

so finally I want that code:

```
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
```

It is possible in smarty to add braking line li element in the foreach loop?

**EDIT.**

When I add:

```
{if $smarty.foreach.sld.iteration == 5}
     <li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
{/if}
```

or

```
{if $lconteiner@index eq 4}
    <li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
{/if}
```

it give me

```
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
```

But when I add:

```
{if $lconteiner@iteration is div by 4}
     <li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
{/if}
```

I give my:

```
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
<li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
<li class="liconteiner col-sm-3">text</li>
```

So this is also wrong, and I don't know why, it supposed to be by every fourth element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**, I cant mark my answer as solved.

Ok, I know why it was not work. I have it in another `{if}`, so solution from my problem was put it outside if statment and use this code:

```
{if $lconteiner@iteration is div by 4}
 <li class="clearfix col-lg-12 visible-lg"></li>
{/if}
```